# Android Pinterest Like AdapterView: How to add LoadMore event and Listener

Tags: android, pull-to-refresh

I am using Pinterest Like AdapterView open source library found at [PinterestLikeAdapterView](https://github.com/huewu/PinterestLikeAdapterView)

The problem is it only support Pull down to Refresh, but I want to use BOTH Pull down to Refresh and Pull up to Loadmore. So I tried to search around and found nothing. I also tried to implement it by myself, but it is not simple. I am a newbie in Android Development with working expierence under 2 months.

I would like to ask for your help to implement Pull up to Loadmore on this Library, or any library that display a grid like Pinterest support Pull down to Refresh and Pull up to Loadmore.

Thank in advanced, and sorry for my bad English :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I'd found a solution. The [Android-PullToRefresh](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh) library is really great, I can use it to implement pull up and pull down for normal GridView. Unfotunately it does not support PLA ListView. So I tried to make it support PLA by duplicated two classes PullToRefreshAdapterViewBase:

```
public abstract class PullToRefreshAdapterViewBase2<T extends PLA_AbsListView> extends PullToRefreshBase<T> implements
    OnScrollListener
```

and

```
public class PullToRefreshGridView2 extends PullToRefreshAdapterViewBase2<MultiColumnListView>
```

Luckily it worked, but I have no idea if it works without bugs. If you have any solution, please let me know.